# Content and design customizer does not match publication WordPress

Tags: css, bug

Good afternoon,

I've built a webshop using WordPress with the plug-ins WooCommerce and Elementor. The website is finished and when I view it in the customizer of WordPress or via the preview link ((https://nura-skincare.com/?customize_changeset_uuid=0a452883-b620-403e-915a-e455585e1712)), everything is correct in terms of content and design. However, when I publish the website and look through the URL (nura-skincare.com), the content is there but the layout and design is not correct.

My tutor indicated that something is going wrong when loading my CSS. See below for the pictures.

[![The first version loads these files.][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsA7n.jpg

[![The version that doesn't work only loads this.][2]][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImqGK.jpg

Does anyone know what I can do about this and if it is at all fixable? I'd love to hear because tonight is my deadline :(

Comment: The URL doesn't work.  I would recommend reaching out to Elementor. The problem with page builders is that they often include their own version of what WP already has, like the Customizer's global settings.  I have worked on sites where Customizer, Elementor and WP Bakery ALL had global settings applied for different areas. Can be a nightmare to figure out.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.